# What is the Success URL for WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using WooCommerce in my web and currently added a gateway plugin. I just want to ask what is the Success URL, Cancel URL and IPN URL in this plugin. Let's take `www.domain.com` as an example in our case.

This is the code:

```
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'woocommerce_FdBank_init', 0);

function woocommerce_FdBank_init() {

class WC_FdBank extends WC_Payment_Gateway {

    /*
     * consrtuct
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $url = includes_url();
        $this->id       = 'FdBank';
        // some code 
        $this->notify_url   = trailingslashit(home_url());

        add_action('woocommerce_update_options_payment_gateways_' . $this->id, array( $this, 'process_admin_options' ) );
        add_action('woocommerce_thankyou_FdBank', array(&$this, 'thankyou_page'));
        add_action('woocommerce_receipt_FdBank', array(&$this, 'receipt_page'));

        add_action('init', array(&$this, 'check_FdBank_response'));
    add_action( 'woocommerce_api_' . strtolower( get_class( $this ) ), array( $this, 'check_FdBank_response' ) );
    }//function construct

    /*
     * Fields for admin
     */
    public function init_form_fields()
    {
        // some code here 
    }//function init_form_fields

    /*
     * All resonses
     * are opereted here
     * +curl from pay server
     */
    public function check_FdBank_response()
    {
        global $woocommerce;


        ##gettin notify Data from pay server
        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
            $aData = $_POST;
            if (!empty($aData)) {
                $order_id = $aData['tran_id'];
                $order_id = preg_replace("/$this->user_code/", '', $order_id, 1);
                $order    = new WC_Order( $order_id );
                if($aData['Tran_Status'] == 'S' && $order->status == 'pending'){
                    $order->update_status('processing');
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        ## fail Action
        $order_id = $aData['tran_id'];
        $order_id = preg_replace("/$this->user_code/", '', $order_id, 1);
        $order    = new WC_Order( $order_id );
        if($_POST['Tran_Status'] == 'F' || $_POST['Tran_Status'] == 'P'){
            if($order->status !=='completed'){
                if($order->status == 'processing'){
                } else {
                    $order -> update_status('failed');
                    $order -> add_order_note('Failed');
                    $order -> add_order_note("Payment failed in bank");
                    $redirect = $order->get_cancel_order_url();
                    return;
                }
            } else {
                wp_redirect($this->notify_url);
            }
        }//function check_FdBank_response

        ##Success Action
        if($_POST['Tran_Status'] == 'S'){
            if($order->status !=='completed'){
                if($order->status == 'processing'){
                    $order->payment_complete();
                    $order->update_status('completed');
                    $order->add_order_note('FdBank payment successful<br/>Bank Ref Number: '.$transid);
                    $order->add_order_note("Thank you for shopping with us. Your account has been charged and your transaction is successful. We will be shipping your order to you soon.");
                    $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
                    $abc = $this->get_return_url( $order );
                    wp_redirect($this->get_return_url( $order ));
                    return;
                }
            } else {
                $order -> update_status('failed');
                $order -> add_order_note('Failed');
                $order -> add_order_note("Payment failed in bank");
                $redirect = $order->get_cancel_order_url();
                wp_redirect($redirect);
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * Gererating from fields
     */
    public function payment_fields()
    {
        if ($this->description){
            echo wpautop(wptexturize($this->description));
        }
    }//function payment_fields

    /*
     * thank you page
     */
    public function thankyou_page()
    {
        if ($this->description){
            echo wpautop(wptexturize($this->description));
        }

        ?><h2><?php _e('Our Details', 'woocommerce') ?></h2>
        <ul class="order_details ppay_details"><?php

        $fields = array(
            'ppay_number'=> __('FdBank ', 'woocommerce')
        );
        foreach ($fields as $key=>$value) :
            if(!empty($this->$key)) :
                echo '<li class="'.$key.'">'.$value.': <strong>'.wptexturize($this->$key).'</strong></li>';
            endif;
        endforeach;
        ?></ul><?php
    }//function thankyou_page

    /*
     * simple reciept
     */
    public function receipt_page($order)
    {
        echo '<p>'.__('Thank you for your order, please click the button below to pay with FdBank .', 'woocommerce').'</p>';
        echo $this->generate_FdBank_form( $order );
    }//function receipt_page

    /*
     * generate_FdBank_form
     * form
     */
    public function generate_FdBank_form( $order_id )
    {
        global $woocommerce;
        $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $redirect_url = $order->get_checkout_order_received_url();
        $redirect_url = add_query_arg( 'wc-api', get_class( $this ), $redirect_url );
        $redirect_url = $redirect_url . '&res=1';


        $params = array(
            // some code 
        );

        $lr_args_array = array();
        foreach($params as $key => $value){
            $lr_args_array[] = "<input type='hidden' name='$key' value='$value'/>";
        }



        return '<form id="FdBank"  action="https://sandbox.domain.com/trans.aspx" method="POST" name="process" >' . implode('', $lr_args_array) . '
                        <input type="submit" class="button-alt button" id="submit_FdBank_payment_form" value="'.__('Pay FdBank ', 'woocommerce').'" /> <a class="button cancel" href="'.esc_url( $order->get_cancel_order_url() ).'">'.__('Cancel order &amp; restore cart', 'woocommerce').'</a>
                </form>';

    }//function generate_FdBank_form

    /*
     * proccess
     */
    public function process_payment( $order_id ) {
        global $woocommerce;
        $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
        return array(
            'result'    => 'success',
            'redirect'  => add_query_arg('order', $order->id, add_query_arg('key', $order->order_key, get_permalink(woocommerce_get_page_id('pay'))))
        );
    }//function process_payment

}
    function woocommerce_add_FdBank_gateway($methods) {
        $methods[] = 'WC_FdBank';
        return $methods;
    }
    add_filter('woocommerce_payment_gateways', 'woocommerce_add_FdBank_gateway' );
}
```

If `check_FdBank_response` is a response handler then what is the URL? After a transaction, which page a user will be redirected to by the gateway, because we are not sending any Return URL or Cancel URL with parameters?

Comment: On a successful order you should go to the "order received" page which is a custom endpoint. You can see the success url in your code already `'redirect'  => add_query_arg('order', $order->id, add_query_arg('key', $order->order_key, get_permalink(woocommerce_get_page_id('pay'))))`.

Comment: if i have a www.domain.com then what is the success url, cancel url and ipn url

Comment: i mean something like www.domain.com/success_url

Comment: WooCommerce doesn't have a static success URL. You can always create a page and have "Success! Thanks for your order" as the content.

Comment: pages are already available i.e thank you page, success page . all i just want to ask what url i set in my account so plugin get response. because bank ask to provide "cancel url" and "success url"

Comment: The existing pages are dynamic (without the order ID and some other data they are useless) and for that reason are not appropriate to pass as a "cancel/success url".

Comment: all i want is set a url in my back account that after a payment they will redirect my client to that url and that url further call this function `check_FdBank_response`

Answer (score 3):

set this url in your bank account

`domain.com/wc-api/WC_FederalBank`

replace `domain.com` with your domain name

now after confirm / cancel transaction your payment gateway will redirect back on this url and it will call your `check_FdBank_response()` function automatically.

`check_FdBank_response()` now validate transaction via using parameters comes with gateway response.
if transaction will confirm it will redirect to thank you page. other wise redirect to cancel url

this is the whole working of this code